# Fetch private subnet through name filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, vpc, private-subnet

I am trying to fetch private subnet-ids through aws cli. I have used this command earlier:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters Name=vpc-id,Values=abc Name=tag:Name,Values=private --query 'Subnets[*].SubnetId'
```

But this time I don't want to provide a static value=private, instead I want to find subnets that contain the word private in their name.

Is there a way to use contains or begins with in the filters for aws cli command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter for subnets that contain `private` in the `Name` tag, you can use:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*private*"
```

If you want to filter for subnets that start with `private` in the `Name` tag, you can use:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=private*"
```